# How do I use Spring Data JPA(Hibernate) ORM mapping to a Oracle Tables from other Schema?

Tags: oracle, orm, spring-data-jpa, schema

The oracle db is version 12c. I use ojdbc8 connector. 
I was only granted access to an account, let's call it schema "USR". Login with USR, I can see tables of another schema, let's call it schema "ADM". There is a table "TGT_TABLE" that I want to map it with JPA inside schema ADM.  And under USR console, I am able to query "select * from ADM.TGT_TABLE" to get correct result. Now I write up the Entity class as:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADM.TGT_TABLE") // or @Table(name = "TGT_TABLE") , Neither worked
public class ApiHeaderLogs {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    String id;
    ....
```

and my config:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.119.125.70:1540:dhtlm4
spring.datasource.username=USR
spring.datasource.password=******
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

and my test:

```
Optional<ApiHeaderLogsEntity> ahl = apiHeaderLogsService.findById(id);
```

I got error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

and the SQL query in console is:

```
select ... from adm_tgt_table where ... //@Table(name = "ADM.TGT_TABLE")
```

Or

```
select ... from tgt_table where ... //@Table(name = "TGT_TABLE")
```

Clearly it does not address the table ADM.TGT_TABLE.
How can I map to ADM.TGT_TABLE?
My experience was mainly on MySQL, which has no account related to schema access, and my colleague already proposed a solution using JDBC directly... which I really want to avoid, please let me know if there is a proper way to handle this, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define explicitely the `table_name` **and** the `schema` in the `@Table` annotation

Example

```
 @Table(name="TGT_TABLE", schema="ADM")
```

See the documentation in [javax.persistence.Table](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Table.html)

Ommiting the schema assumes the deafult owner of the connecting session, which leads to an error.

Neither can you pass a qualified name (ADM.TGT_TABLE) as a table name.

Comment: In many oracle setups, the schema can differ between environments and needs to be stored in config. Annotations are built at compile time hence cannot use properties from config. Is there any way to specify the schema at runtime? I tried it using PhysicalNamingStrategy but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You are right @KristopherNoronha though this is probably not the *best* design. Similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61760869/4808122) the answer is *multi-tenacy*