# Change database schema during runtime based on logged in user and shared schema

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Springboot 2 with hibernate and spring data JPA.

Previously we were using the JDBC template and there we are adding schema name into SQL query based on logged-in user. like -

```
String sql = "Select * from " + scheama + ".table"
```

Now we need a similar kind of support in hibernate.

I found a couple of similar question on stack overflow like -

- [Change database schema during runtime based on logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357367/change-database-schema-during-runtime-based-on-logged-in-user)
- [Spring JPA: Providing Schema Name Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61760869/spring-jpa-providing-schema-name-dynamically)

We have schema per user and also have some shared schema that does not depends on the logged-in user.
In the above example I can handle schema for the logged-in users but is there any way to handle both user schema and shared schema.

Code sample to get schema -

```
String sceama = this.companyService.getScheama(this.getUserCompany(request.getHeader("selectedCompany")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found two solutions, both solved my problem.

**Solution 1 -**
Created a hibernate interceptor and add dynamic schema in SQL query.

https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-dynamic-table-routin

```
public class HibernateInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Override
        public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
              String prepedStatement = super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
              prepedStatement = prepedStatement.replaceAll("secure.identitymanagement", "my_dynamic_goodness");
              return prepedStatement;
        }
    
    }
```

**Solution 2 -**
Configured two different schema - one for shared/common schema and another one for the user-specific schema.

This blog explains both "Database per tenant" and "Schema per tenant".
https://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2020/09/19/multi-tenancy-with-spring-boot-part1/

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by configuring multi-tenancy with Hibernate. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy